# How to handle event within three classes

Tags: c#, eventhandler

Look at my code pls. I have ThirdClass to triger an event. In Second Class I Handle that event. But how to handle that event in my Program Class. In this class I have no ThirdClass object to subscribe an event. Do I have to declerate another event in Second class In order to triger MyPurpose() method?

```
public class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] ars)
    {
        Program myProgram = new Program();

        SecondClass second = new SecondClass();
        second.LaunchSecondClass();

        //A want to run this method when OnCounted event fired
        //...
        //myProgram.MyPurpose();
        //...
    }


    public void MyPurpose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program Class here!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public void LaunchSecondClass()
    {
        ThirdClass third = new ThirdClass();
        third.myEvent += this.OnCounted;

        third.count();
    }

    private void OnCounted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Class Here.");
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }
}



public class ThirdClass
{
    public event EventHandler myEvent;

    public void count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            //Only for testing
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        OnCounted();
    }

    protected virtual void OnCounted()
    {
        if (myEvent != null)
            myEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: in short... yes ... congratulations on answering your own question

Comment: There are many ways to do what you want. You can do as you said, publishing a new event on `SecondClass`, or can expose your ThirdClass as a property of the `SecondClass` and handle this one on the main program, or even pass your method to execute thru your `SecondClass` constructor...

Comment: There's no war around that. However, you might want to reconsider the use of `SecondClass`. Maybe it's useful that `SecondClass` also exposes an event, or maybe `SecondClass` is redundant and you can refactor its functionality across `FirstClass` and `ThirdClass`. If you're bothered by a pass-through, some refactoring and reordering of responsibility is likely needed.

Comment: Diego, I can expose ThirdClass as a Property of SecondClass but how to handle this on the main program? I can't put second.thirdClass.myEvent += Program.OnCounted; in Program Class becouse ThirdClass instance is created in specyfic circumstances by SecondClass. Talking about passing mathod you mean using delegate?

Comment: Glubus, thx for your replay but the code I posted is much more simple then my project. I wanted to show only overview to find out is there another way to accomplish my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of way to do what you want, as I said. The goal can be achieved, despite this, I highly recommend you to pay attention to @Glubus 's comment, .

Here's three of this ways:

**Option 1 - Expose a new Event on `SecondClass`**

```
public class SecondClass
{
    public event EventHandler SecondEvent;

    public void LaunchSecondClass()
    {
        ThirdClass third = new ThirdClass();
        third.myEvent += this.OnCounted;

        third.count();
    }

    private void OnCounted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Class Here.");
        //Console.ReadLine();
        SecondEvent?.Invoke(); // Based on C# 6
    }
}
```

And in your main program:

```
static void Main(string[] ars)
{
    Program myProgram = new Program();

    SecondClass second = new SecondClass();
    second.SecondEvent += MyPurpose;
    second.LaunchSecondClass();
}
```

**Option 2 - Expose the `ThirdClass` on `SecondClass` as a property**

```
public class SecondClass
{
    public ThirdClass ThirdClass { get; }

    public SecondClass()
    {
        ThirdClass = new ThirdClass();
        ThirdClass.myEvent += this.OnCounted;
    }

    public void LaunchSecondClass()
    {
        if(ThirdClass == null)
            ThirdClass = new ThirdClass();

        ThirdClass.count();
    }

    private void OnCounted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Class Here.");
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And in your main program:

```
static void Main(string[] ars)
{
    Program myProgram = new Program();

    SecondClass second = new SecondClass();
    second.ThirdClass.myEvent += MyPurpose;
    second.LaunchSecondClass();
}
```

**Option 3 - Pass and `Action` (Delegate) to be executed by the `SecondClass`'s method**

```
public class SecondClass
{
    public void LaunchSecondClass(Action action)
    {
        ThirdClass third = new ThirdClass();
        third.myEvent += this.OnCounted;

        if(action != null)
            third.myEvent += (o, a) => action.Invoke();

        third.count();
    }

    private void OnCounted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Class Here.");
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And in your main program:

```
static void Main(string[] ars)
{
    Program myProgram = new Program();

    SecondClass second = new SecondClass();
    second.LaunchSecondClass(MyPurpose);
}
```

Remember that there are no guarantees of a best practicle choice without know the real scenario where you're intent to apply it. So, maybe you must [search up a design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns) to your problem and follow up the SOLID principles when planning your solutions

This is the best way to get a clean and efficient code .

Here's a good read about this topics:

- [Design Patterns](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd5be5/design-patterns-in-net/)
- [SOLID Principles](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/)

I Hope it help you, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Thank you very much Diego, you helped me a lot. In my sytuation: Option 1 works perfectly. Option 2 also works fine but I cant use it becouse there is no instance of ThirdClass when I attach an eventhandler to the event in Program class (second.ThirdClass.myEvent += MyPurpose;). This instance is created later by additional method in SecondClass. Option 3 is new for me and I'm going to learn it :-). Thank you.